# SQL: how to calculate month to date P&L (proft and loss) with SQL select query?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I need to calculate monthly-to-date (MTD) P&L (Profit and Loss) for a series of financial transactions. Suppose the tables below, one with transactions and another with prices:

Transactions:

```
Ticket_number   Asset_code  dt_ticket   Cost
1                  1        2014-12-05  700
2                  1        2015-01-30  750
3                  1        2015-07-15  800
```

Prices:

```
 Asset_code | Dt_price  | PU
    1       | 2014-12-30| 800
    1       | 2015-06-30| 780
    1       | 2015-07-15| 715
    1       | 2015-07-31| 720
```

Suppose all quantities equals One, and I have more than on asset ( = asset_code [1...n]) 
So, if I were on July,31, I would see something like:

```
Tkt_num |Asset_code|dt_tkt    |  cost  |Prev. Price  |Closing Price | MTD P&L
  1     | 1        |2014-12-05|  700      | 780         |  720         | -60
  2     | 1        |2015-01-30|  750      | 780         |  720         | -60
  3     | 1        |2015-07-15|  800      | 800         |  720         | -80
```

Formula: MTD = Closing Price (on Jul,31) – Price on date [max(EOM Date, ticket_date)] 
In the table above, the previous price for the first and second rows should be the price as of June,30, and the price for the last row should be cost of this transactions, as it occurred after the last month closing (or in the same month). 
My question is: Can I calculate this MTD P&L with SQL Select queries? 
I know I can use PHP, calculating row by row, but I wanna know if it can be done with SQL Select.

Comment: Is your 3rd table correct? It seems like the Prev for 3 should be 780, and for 2 should be 800, and 1 is not calculable from this data.

Comment: As a comment, I recommend you store dates in the 'yyyy-mm-dd' format, and use a MySQL `DATE` type if you are not already.

Comment: Thanks, McAdam331. It uses yyyy-mm-dd format. I manually created this examples to post here, and as I'm used to dd/dd/yyyy (Brazilian format), I manually edited to US Format , mm/dd/yyyy. I'm updating to yyyy-mm-dd format.

Comment: Holmes: yes, it's correct. Previous Price for row 1 and 2 should be 780, as of June,30. When calculating the profit or loss for one month , one should calculate the price variation between last day of month  (in this case June,30 x July,31). One asset valued 780 on June,30 and 720 on July,31, so it lose value between this dates ( 780 - 720= -60). For row 3, it didn't exist in the end of last month (June,30). So, the monthly P&L is the difference between the begin/cost price and the price at the end of the current month ( 800 - 720 = -80)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am going to break this up and solve it one piece at a time. I recommend you store a variable to keep track of the closing date, so this query can be rerun in the future easily:

```
SET @closing_date := '2015-07-31';
```

To get the previous price, consider the following steps:

- If the ticket occurred in the same month/year as the closing date, the previous price is the same as the ticket cost.
- If the ticket occurred in a previous month/yeah, the previous price is the price as of the end of the most recent month.

In your example, you want to get the most recent price that occurs before 2015-07-01. Because you can have multiple asset_codes, I recommend you get the latest date for each asset_code like this:

```
SELECT asset_code, MAX(price_date) AS latestPriceDate
FROM prices
WHERE price_date < DATE_FORMAT(@closing_date, '%Y-%m-01')
GROUP BY asset_code;
```

To get the prices for those dates, you'll need to join back to the original table:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM prices p
JOIN(
  SELECT asset_code, MAX(price_date) AS latestPriceDate
  FROM prices
  WHERE price_date < DATE_FORMAT(@closing_date, '%Y-%m-01')
  GROUP BY asset_code) tmp ON tmp.asset_code = p.asset_code AND tmp.latestPriceDate = p.price_date;
```

Now you can take that subquery and join it to the transactions table. You will need a `CASE` statement to check if the date is within the month/year of closing. If it is less than that, you can select the transaction cost. I also adjusted the join condition to only pull transactions less than or equal to the closing date:

```
SELECT t.ticket_number, 
  t.asset_code, 
  t.ticket_date, 
  CASE WHEN MONTH(t.ticket_date) = MONTH(@closing_date) AND YEAR(t.ticket_date) = YEAR(@closing_date) THEN cost ELSE p.pu END AS 'Previous Price'
FROM transactions t
JOIN(
  SELECT p.*
  FROM prices p
  JOIN(
    SELECT asset_code, MAX(price_date) AS latestPriceDate
    FROM prices
    WHERE price_date < DATE_FORMAT(@closing_date, '%Y-%m-01')
    GROUP BY asset_code) tmp ON tmp.asset_code = p.asset_code AND tmp.latestPriceDate = p.price_date
  ) p ON p.asset_code = t.asset_code AND t.ticket_date <= @closing_date;
```

---

To get the closing price for each asset code, you will have to do a similar aggregation. First get the latest date less than or equal to closing, then join back to the table to get the values:

```
SELECT p.asset_code, p.pu
FROM prices p
JOIN(
  SELECT asset_code, MAX(price_date) AS latestPriceDate
  FROM prices
  WHERE price_date <= @closing_date
  GROUP BY asset_code) tmp ON tmp.asset_code = p.asset_code AND tmp.latestPriceDate = p.price_date;
```

Once you have that, you can work it into your overall query like this:

```
SELECT t.ticket_number, 
  t.asset_code, 
  t.ticket_date, 
  CASE WHEN MONTH(t.ticket_date) = MONTH(@closing_date) AND YEAR(t.ticket_date) = YEAR(@closing_date) THEN cost ELSE p.pu END AS 'Previous Price',
  cp.pu AS closing_price
FROM transactions t
JOIN(
  SELECT p.*
  FROM prices p
  JOIN(
    SELECT asset_code, MAX(price_date) AS latestPriceDate
    FROM prices
    WHERE price_date < DATE_FORMAT(@closing_date, '%Y-%m-01')
    GROUP BY asset_code) tmp ON tmp.asset_code = p.asset_code AND tmp.latestPriceDate = p.price_date
  ) p ON p.asset_code = t.asset_code AND t.ticket_date <= @closing_date
JOIN(
  SELECT p.asset_code, p.pu
  FROM prices p
  JOIN(
    SELECT asset_code, MAX(price_date) AS latestPriceDate
    FROM prices
    WHERE price_date <= @closing_date
    GROUP BY asset_code) tmp ON tmp.asset_code = p.asset_code AND tmp.latestPriceDate = p.price_date
  ) cp ON cp.asset_code = p.asset_code;
```

---

The last thing to do is get your P&L column, which you can do by selecting pu - closing_price - previous_price. Unfortunately you cannot use the column aliases in your select, so you'll have to write out the formulas again:

```
SELECT t.ticket_number, 
  t.asset_code, 
  t.ticket_date, 
  CASE WHEN MONTH(t.ticket_date) = MONTH(@closing_date) AND YEAR(t.ticket_date) = YEAR(@closing_date) THEN cost ELSE p.pu END AS 'Previous Price',
  cp.pu AS 'Closing Price',
  cp.pu - CASE WHEN MONTH(t.ticket_date) = MONTH(@closing_date) AND YEAR(t.ticket_date) = YEAR(@closing_date) THEN cost ELSE p.pu END AS 'P&L'
FROM transactions t
JOIN(
  SELECT p.*
  FROM prices p
  JOIN(
    SELECT asset_code, MAX(price_date) AS latestPriceDate
    FROM prices
    WHERE price_date < DATE_FORMAT(@closing_date, '%Y-%m-01')
    GROUP BY asset_code) tmp ON tmp.asset_code = p.asset_code AND tmp.latestPriceDate = p.price_date
  ) p ON p.asset_code = t.asset_code AND t.ticket_date <= @closing_date
JOIN(
  SELECT p.asset_code, p.pu
  FROM prices p
  JOIN(
    SELECT asset_code, MAX(price_date) AS latestPriceDate
    FROM prices
    WHERE price_date <= @closing_date
    GROUP BY asset_code) tmp ON tmp.asset_code = p.asset_code AND tmp.latestPriceDate = p.price_date
  ) cp ON cp.asset_code = p.asset_code;
```

Here is an [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/54c5f/7) example using your sample data. If you don't want to use a variable you don't have to, just replace @closing_date with your date in each spot.